# Partition by Key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to apply partition on a table with million of rows. E.g I have the following attributes `(Id,Devicecode(varchar),Latitude ,Longitude , time/date)` and I want to apply partition on device code, I know that partition can only be applied to primary key in this case if Id is the `primary key` then `Device code` should also be the `primary key`. What I didn't get is the `foreign key` limitation in mysql documentation. Does it says that I can't apply partitioning if the attribute is a `foreign key`? what can be the other limitations? Also "Partitions 4" means I want to create 4 partitions right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOC: [18.6 Restrictions and Limitations on Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations.html)

> Foreign keys not supported for partitioned InnoDB tables. Partitioned
>   tables using the InnoDB storage engine do not support foreign keys.
>   More specifically, this means that the following two statements are
>   true:
>
> No definition of an InnoDB table employing user-defined partitioning
>   may contain foreign key references; no InnoDB table whose definition
>   contains foreign key references may be partitioned.
>
> No InnoDB table definition may contain a foreign key reference to a
>   user-partitioned table; no InnoDB table with user-defined partitioning
>   may contain columns referenced by foreign keys.
>
> The scope of the restrictions just listed includes all tables that use
>   the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: Ok it means that the table we are applying partitioning on SHOULDN'T have ANY foreign key right? (Id,Devicecode(varchar),Latitude ,Longitude , time/date) none of the attributes should be foreign key?

Comment: Yes. You understood correctly - "no InnoDB table whose definition contains foreign key references may be partitioned"

Comment: Ok great! Another thing is that possible to apply partitioning on non primary key attribute? Like I want to apply partition on "DeviceCode" where as Id is the PK. Is that possible?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-key.html "Any columns used as the partitioning key must comprise part or all of the table's primary key, if the table has one. Where no column name is specified as the partitioning key, the table's primary key is used, if there is one. "